# Trying to write a Python-based group classifier

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to divide a group of 100 people into 8 groups based on their preferences and subsequently, my own criteria. I will walk you through a quick example of the idea. Bear with me, my question is at the bottom!

John Doe has filled in a form that contains 8 different groups, out of which John had to select his top 3. This is what it would look like:

```
 1: Group 6;
 2: Group 4;
 3: Group 1;
```

Obviously, it would be great to be able to put every person into his or her number 1 choice. Unfortunately, this isn't possible, and I have to divide the people. I want to be able to divide based on *age*, *sex* and *preference*. I want to have at least 4 different ages in a group, a 50/50 division of sexes and to put everyone in as high as possible. And now for the question:

Is there, to your knowledge, a script for this? Do I need to make one from scratch? If so, what concepts do I need to bear in mind?

Comment: You should research *"clustering"*.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have much to do with python. Feels more suited to [Programmers SEx](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In general, please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far! Jon, would K-means clustering make sense in this case? And Quirk, I understand this forum is more about programming errors and hands-on help, but this is rather a more philosophical question here; I will see if the Programmers SEx community can help me :)